# Computing Boston and TTC in Python

Tags: mechanism-design, algorithms, python, matching

This is somewhat of a follow up question to [Available code for computing solutions to matching algorithms?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1638/available-code-for-computing-solutions-to-matching-algorithms).

In the above question, I got great answers, but all of them were for `R`.

I am now programming a lab experiment in [otree](http://www.otree.org/), which means I am working with Python.

It is fairly easy to find code in `python` solving matching problems using the Deferred Acceptance mechanism, but I wondered if anyone knew of `python` code for some of the other common mechanisms in the  literature. Specifically, I am looking for `python` code for

- The Boston mechanism (aka. Immediate acceptance)
- The Top-trading cycle algorithm

In the best of the worlds, these codes would

- Be compatible with the school choice model (i.e. many-to-one matching problem in which agents in one side of the "market" can be matched to many agents on the other side)
- Allow for constrains on the lenght of the preference list agents can report (see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002205310900057X)

However, I would already be very happy with `python` code for Boston and TTC, even if the two last features are not implemented.

Comment: Just in case, Python can run R. See eg `rpy2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting together some code to compute the assignment under Boston and deferred acceptance. It can be found at https://github.com/vanderlindenma/school_choice_python.

The code there uses and modifies former code from Jeremy Kun, stable-marriage, (2014), GitHub repository, https://github.com/j2kun/stable-marriages, described in one of Jeremy's blog posts at http://jeremykun.com/2014/04/02/stable-marriages-and-designing-markets/.

I hope to expend on the code that’s currently available and add more functionalities soon. Any participation is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I found one implementation of TTC in `python` at http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/377004-algorithmic-game-theory-top-trading-cycle-procedure/?ref=dzone.

However, it does not seem to include the two additional features I was mentionning.

With of without these two features : I would still love to hear about more implementation of TTC, and about implementations of Boston.

Comment: I'm the author of that article. I cross-post both on Dream.in.Code and my personal blog. The math is cleaner on my blog, which supports LaTeX rendering. For reference: https://michaellevet.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/algorithmic-game-theory-house-allocation-problem/